# Problem with TPH Inheritance mapping in EF 4.1 with Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have these classes in my ASP.NET MVC app:

```
public abstract class Person {
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person {
    public DateTime RegisteredOnUtc { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Person {
    public string LessonName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person> {
    public PersonMap()
        : base() {

        this.HasKey(t => t.PersonId);

        this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.LastName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.ToTable("Persons");

        this.Property(t => t.PersonId).HasColumnName("PersonId");
        this.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
        this.Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");

        this.Map<Student>(x => x.Requires("IsStudent").HasValue(true));
        this.Map<Teacher>(x => x.Requires("IsStudent").HasValue(false));
    }
}

public class StudentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student> {
    public StudentMap()
        : base() {

        this.HasKey(t => t.PersonId); // Is this need or not???

        this.ToTable("Persons"); // Is this need or not???

        this.Property(t => t.RegisteredOnUtc).HasColumnName("RegisteredOn");
    }
}

public class TeacherMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Teacher> {
    public TeacherMap()
        : base() {

        this.HasKey(t => t.PersonId); // Is this need or not???

        this.ToTable("Persons"); // Is this need or not???

        this.Property(t => t.LessonName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.LessonName).HasColumnName("Lesson");
    }
}

public class PersonContext : DbContext {

    public ObjectContext ObjectContext {
        get {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        }
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StudentMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TeacherMap());
    }

    public void Detach(object entity) {
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        objectContext.Detach(entity);
    }
}
```

But, when I run the app, get this error:

***The property `'PersonId'` is not a declared property on type `'Student'`. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the `Ignore` method or `NotMappedAttribute` data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.***

**And if remove** `this.HasKey(t => t.PersonId);` from the `Student` and `Teacher`, this error will be thrown:

***The given key was not present in the dictionary.***

Have you any idea to resolve this please? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's problems with server. Try to paste your code to a simple console application and test it. I publish example how I did this.

Answer (score 1):

I little rewrite your code, it takes what you want:

You have the PersonId as primary key
and all other limits are present.

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    [Column("RegisteredOn")]
    public DateTime RegisteredOnUtc { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LessonName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Map<Student>(x => x.Requires("IsStudent").HasValue(true));
        Map<Teacher>(x => x.Requires("IsStudent").HasValue(false));
    }
}

public class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMap());
    }

    public void Detach(object entity)
    {
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        objectContext.Detach(entity);
    }
}
```

Your DB looks like:

[image]

**add code for test**

```
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
    using System.Data.Objects;

    namespace ConsoleApplication5
    {
        public abstract class Person
        {
            public int PersonId { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Student : Person
        {
            public DateTime RegisteredOnUtc { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }

        public class Teacher : Person
        {
            public string LessonName { get; set; }
        }

        public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
        {
            public PersonMap()
                : base()
            {

                this.HasKey(t => t.PersonId);

                this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                this.Property(t => t.LastName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                this.ToTable("Persons");

                this.Property(t => t.PersonId).HasColumnName("PersonId");
                this.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
                this.Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");

                this.Map<Student>(x => x.Requires("IsStudent").HasValue(true));
                this.Map<Teacher>(x => x.Requires("IsStudent").HasValue(false));
            }
        }

        public class StudentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
        {
            public StudentMap()
                : base()
            {

                this.Property(t => t.RegisteredOnUtc).HasColumnName("RegisteredOn");
            }
        }

        public class TeacherMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Teacher>
        {
            public TeacherMap()
                : base()
            {

                this.Property(t => t.LessonName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                this.Property(t => t.LessonName).HasColumnName("Lesson");
            }
        }

        public class PersonContext : DbContext
        {

            public ObjectContext ObjectContext
            {
                get
                {
                    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
                }
            }

            public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
                modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMap());
                modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StudentMap());
                modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TeacherMap());
            }

            public void Detach(object entity)
            {
                var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
                objectContext.Detach(entity);
            }
        }

        public class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                var personContext = new PersonContext();
                personContext.Database.Delete();
                personContext.Database.Create();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I write in my question, that I test the app with and without that line, you are speaking about. NOT difference, doesn't work still. Also, I now this way you use, but in this case, I can't use it. Thanks

Comment: I remove all codes and recreate them again, and problem resolved! I never understand where was the problem! Your code (and @John Allers's too) was the code (and solution) that I test before, but not worked! I can't understand. So thanks to your helps. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing both of these lines from StudentMap and TeacherMap?

```
this.HasKey(t => t.PersonId); // Is this need or not???

this.ToTable("Persons"); // Is this need or not???
```

I copied your code and ran it without these lines and it worked just fine.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the exception when you remove those lines?

Comment: I think mu mistake is in another place. That code (above) is a part of full code. I think, I must remove all codes, and trace it step by step. Thanks to your help. regards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's TPH inheritance if you include the Students and Teachers in the PersonContext class. Isn't the whole point of TPH to just have one table, the Person table? I'd remove these two lines

```
public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
```

If you look at [this walkthrough](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), particularly the 'Adding the Person Entity Type to the Model' section you'll see what I mean. I'm not sure if this has much to do with your particular problem but you might want to note it anyway.